# Background is not transparent on popup activity android Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

i have an activity which is to be converted to an popup. so i used

> SetTheme(Android.Resource.Style.ThemeDialog);

to make it look like an popup. but the problem is it looks like a popup but previous activity is not visible on back. i get a black background. what i am doing wrong. little help will be great.

Comment: Did you get the solution for this?

Comment: no but i got it working by changing it as Dialog Fragment. @AdarshVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i couldn't fix it using `SetTheme(Android.Resource.Style.ThemeDialog);`

so i changed the activity to dialog fragment and now it works fine.